# Audience rules depending on user domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, audience-targeting, domain

I have 4 different domains in my office 365:

- @uno.com
- @dos.com
- @tres.com
- @cuatro.com

I want to create an audience for each domain and create a rule that makes that possible. Every user that has `@dos.com` domain is in the 'Dos' audience and so on.

My problem is that I can't find the rule to make this possible and I can't make tests every time I want because the compilation of audiences are only once a week and I can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Create an audience of your preference. I used the domain name I'm targeting. In the Audience rules section, click Add rule. Find the Work email property, switch the dropdown to 'contains' and add the target domain.

As you see in the image, this audience is not yet compiled, and we have to wait until it gets compiled before we can use this audience. Unfortunately, we can't force compilation :(

When compiled, you can see which users are affected in the 'view membership' link.

More to read: [Manage SharePoint Online audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-SharePoint-Online-audiences-1806ec78-1d4e-4620-8a89-89d6a38c9c33?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Thanks so much! Let's wait to this friday to check the results on the compilation.